# Binary and linear search methods for a number-guessing game

Tags: binary-search, number-guessing-game, delphi, pascal

This is a code written is Pascal (Delphi). It asks the user to think of a number between `min_` and `max_` and then guesses the number using either a Binary or a Linear method.

```
  program BandLSearch;

  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

  {$R *.res}

  uses
    System.SysUtils;

  var
    min_, max_: integer; // set the max and min to check between the two (inclusive)

    BinorLin: string;  // Get user input as to which method they wish to use

  procedure Linear();
    {
    This uses a linear search technique to guess the number.
    It will ask min_ then min_ +1 etc up to max_. e.g. 1, 2, 3, ... , 99, 100
    }
    var
      input: string;
      count: integer; // For the foor loop


    begin
      for count := min_ to max_ do  // loop from min to max and ask if the number is corect, one by one
        begin
          write('Is your number ',count,'? Y or N? > ');
          readln(input);
          if (input = 'Y') or (input = 'y') then
            begin
              writeln('Found your number, it is ',count);
              readln;       // Prevent the code ending without being able to read the output.
              break
            end
          else
            begin
              if count = max_ then  //If they have reached max and not said yes, they are lying
                begin
                  writeln('You have cheated');
                  readln;
                end;
            end;

        end;
    end;

  procedure Binary();
    {
    This uses a linear search technique to guess the number
    It will ask (min_ + max_)/2 and the user says too high or too low.
    Depending on the response, it will set either min_ or max_ to the guessed number
    Eventually it narrows down, eg:
    50, 75, 62, 68, 65, 63, 64
     L   H   L   H   H   L   C
    }
    var
      input: string;
      guess, preGuess: integer; // For the current computer guess
      goesTaken : integer; // To monitor the guesses needed
      end_: integer;  // Will increase for each guess that max_ = min_

    begin

      preGuess := -1; // Will not be the guess.
      goesTaken := 0;
      end_ := 0;

      while end_ < 2 do  //when it is 2, it will have guessed all the numbers.
        begin

          inc(goesTaken);

          guess := (max_ + min_) div 2;



          writeln('Is your number ',guess,'?');
          writeln('If guess is too high enter H, if it''s too low, enter L.');
          write('If the guess is corect, enter C > ');
          readln(input);

          if input = 'H' then  // Number is too high, so guess lower
            max_ := guess - 1
          else
            if input = 'L' then  // Number is too low, so guess higher
              min_ := guess + 1
            else                 // Number is correct
              begin
                writeln('Found your number, it is ',guess);
                writeln('It took me ',goesTaken,' goes.');
                readln;
                break
              end;

          if guess = preGuess then // If the computer asks the same number two times in a row, the user has cheated.
            begin
              writeln('You have cheated');
              readln;
              break
            end
          else
            preGuess := guess;

          if (max_ = min_) then // If min is the same as max, then 1 go later the code can exit.
            begin
              end_ := end_ + 1;
            end;

        end;

    end;

  begin

    min_ := 0;
    max_ := 100;

    writeln('Think of a number between ',min_, ' and ', max_, '. I will guess it.');

    write('Do you want to use a (l)inear or a (b)inary search? > ');
    readln(BinorLin);

    if BinorLin = 'l' then   // User input comparison
      begin
        writeln('Starting Linear Search...');
        Linear();
      end
    else;
      begin
        if BinorLin = 'b' then
          begin
            writeln('Starting Binary Search...');
            Binary();
          end
        else  // didn't enter 'l' or 'b'
          begin
            exit
          end;
      end;    
  end.
```

This is a high school assignment, however I have already handed it in (today) for marking. I'd be interested in the opinion of more than my teacher.

Answer (score 2):

- I would rather use Free Pascal than Delphi, makes code more promptly editable;
- You should avoid nested `if`'s, specially in pascal, where you can easily get lost otherwise. Use the `case` statement instead.
- pascal do not use `camelCase` but `PascalCase`.
- you should use `const` for constants, and name them like `PASCAL_CONSTANT`.
- you should prefix your own variables to avoid getting lost in terms of scope and variables types:

  - `F` for class fields;
  - `T` for objects;
  - `A` for property (generic) values;
  - `I` for integers, for local variables
  - `S` for strings, for local variables
  - and so on
- `starting code` messages should be put at the starting of the code, i.e., first line after a `begin` statement of the corresponding procedure, function or program.
- It is not necessary to write the `()` for methods that does not require entries.
- Pascal is case insensitive. However, it does not mean you should not be consistent with existing code: you should use [WriteLn](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=WriteLn), instead writeln, for example.

Putting all together:

```
program BandLSearch;

uses SysUtils;

var
  SInput: string;  // Get user input as to which method they wish to use

const // set the max and min to check between the two (inclusive)
  MIN_VALUE : integer = 0;
  MAX_VALUE : integer = 100;

{ This uses a linear search technique to guess the number.
  It will ask MIN_VALUE then MIN_VALUE +1 up to MAX_VALUE. e.g. 1, 2, 3, ... , 99, 100 }
procedure Linear;
var
  ICount: integer; // For the foor loop

begin
  WriteLn('Starting Linear Search...');
  for ICount := MIN_VALUE to MAX_VALUE do // loop from min to max and ask if the number is corect, one by one
    begin
      Write('Is your number ',ICount,'? Y or N? > ');
      ReadLn(SInput);

      SInput := UpperCase(SInput);
      if SInput = 'Y' then
        begin
          WriteLn('Found your number, it is ',ICount);
          ReadLn; // Prevent the code ending without being able to read the output.
          Break
        end;

      if ICount = MAX_VALUE then  //If they have reached max and not said yes, they are lying
        begin
          WriteLn('You have cheated.');
          ReadLn;
        end;
    end;
end;

{  This uses a binary search technique to guess the number
  It will ask (MIN_VALUE + MAX_VALUE)/2 and the user says too high or too low.
  Depending on the response, it will set either MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE to the guessed number
  Eventually it narrows down, eg:
  50, 75, 62, 68, 65, 63, 64
  L   H   L   H   H   L   C }
procedure Binary;
var
  IGuess, IPreGuess, // For the current computer guess
  IGoesTaken,        // To monitor the guesses needed
  IEnd: integer;     // Will increase for each guess that MAX_VALUE = MIN_VALUE

begin
  WriteLn('Starting Binary Search...');
  IPreGuess := -1; // Will not be the guess.
  IGoesTaken := 0;
  IEnd := 0;

  repeat
    Inc(IGoesTaken);
    IGuess := (MAX_VALUE + MIN_VALUE) div 2;

    WriteLn('Is your number ',IGuess,'?');
    WriteLn('If guess is too high enter H, if it''s too low, enter L.');
    Write('If the guess is correct, enter C or Y > ');
    ReadLn(SInput);

    SInput := UpperCase(SInput);
    case SInput of  
      'H': MAX_VALUE := IGuess - 1; // Number is too high, so guess lower
      'L': MIN_VALUE := IGuess + 1; // Number is too low, so guess higher
      'C', 'Y':
        begin
          WriteLn('Found your number, it is ',IGuess);
          WriteLn('It took me ',IGoesTaken,' goes.');
          ReadLn;
          Break;
        end;
    else // Number is correct    

    end;

    if IGuess = IPreGuess then // If the computer asks the same number two times in a row, the user has cheated.
      begin
        WriteLn('Sorry, I did not undertand you (or you have cheated).');
        ReadLn;
        Break;
      end
    else
      IPreGuess := IGuess;

    if MAX_VALUE = MIN_VALUE then
      IEnd := IEnd + 1; // If min is the same as max, then 1 go later the code can exit.
  until IEnd >= 2;
end;

begin
  WriteLn('Think of a number between ',MIN_VALUE, ' and ', MAX_VALUE, '. I will guess it.');
  Write('Do you want to use a (l)inear or a (b)inary search? > ');
  ReadLn(SInput);

  SInput := LowerCase(SInput);
  case SInput of // User input comparison
    'l': Linear;
    'b': Binary;
  else
    Exit;
  end; 
end.
```

Comment: `FTA` is common in Pascal, Free Pascal and Delphi. For local variables there are no standards, but you will frequently find `S` for local strings and `I` for loop integers. `IS` is an extension considering that fact.

Comment: @holroy, after all, the point is not getting lost. Works for me :)

Comment: I'm all for clarity in naming, but in C# or Python naming standards is used where you don't need prefixes, but rather use variations on camelCase or PascalCase or snake_case. And you should normally not have a problem knowing the type of a variable as that should be given by the name/context. The same applies for scope, as if your code is so long you don't have control of the scope you should add some procedures/methods/functions to narrow down the scope. But YMMV...

Comment: For me works like that, `PascalMethod`, `LPascalLocalVariable`, `AMethodValue`, `FFieldAttribute`, `TAbstractObject`. As you can see, methods are not prefixed. But, again, for local variables there are no standards as far as I know.

Comment: I will think about these. I essentially have to use Delphi but I'll consider the others. I especially like the use of case statements but I'm unsure the variable prefix is needed, and some of the other naming conventions seem strange. Thanks though.

Comment: Again, the point is not getting lost. Of course, you can check for yourself http://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/examples/

Comment: I'm also a little confused as to the `WriteLn` over `writeln` - is that also the standard. Bear in mind I am asking for Delphi not free Pascal / Lazarus. What do you mean by getting lost? As in not knowing what variable does what?

Comment: Prefixing is the (Delphi/Free) Pascal way of better remember what your variables were created for (not getting lost), take a look at http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/l/bldnc.htm, for example.

Comment: Pascal is case insensitive. It does not mean you should not be consistent with existing code: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=WriteLn